# How to get a value from code mirror in react js?

Tags: reactjs, input, use-state, react-codemirror2

I am trying to get a value from the code mirror input field but I don't know why I am not getting the value from code mirror input field

```
import CodeMirror from "@uiw/react-codemirror";
import { markdown, markdownLanguage } from "@codemirror/lang-markdown";
import { languages } from "@codemirror/language-data";

export default function Editor() {
    const [get, set] = useState("");
    console.log(get); {/* doesn't display anything */}
     
    return (
      <>
        <CodeMirror
          value={get}
          extensions={[
            markdown({ base: markdownLanguage, codeLanguages: languages }),
          ]}
          onInput={(e) => set(e.target.value)}
        />
      </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onChange` handler can output the value as below.

```
import { markdown, markdownLanguage } from "@codemirror/lang-markdown";
import { languages } from "@codemirror/language-data";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Editor() {
  const [get, set] = useState("");
  console.log(get);

  return (
    <>
      <CodeMirror
        value={get}
        extensions={[
          markdown({ base: markdownLanguage, codeLanguages: languages })
        ]}
        onChange={(value) => set(value)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Working example

[image: Edit dank-sun-dm1m8v]

Comment: Perfect. May I know what's the different between  onChange={(value) => set(value)} and onChange={(e) => set(e.target.value)}

Comment: That's what they support, onChange gets called with the value, not the event when you type.

Answer (score 2):

Try `useEffect` hook, it calls the function inside whenever variable in second argument array changes, in this specific scenario when `get` changes.

```
import CodeMirror from "@uiw/react-codemirror";
import { markdown, markdownLanguage } from "@codemirror/lang-markdown";
import { languages } from "@codemirror/language-data";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Editor() {
    const [get, set] = useState("");
    
    useEffect(() => {
       console.log(get) //gets called whenever get state changes
    }, [get])
     
    return (
      <>
        <CodeMirror
          value={get}
          extensions={[
            markdown({ base: markdownLanguage, codeLanguages: languages }),
          ]}
          onInput={(e) => set(e.target.value)}
        />
      </>
    );
}
```

Comment: it is saying undefined in useEffect  console.log(get)

Comment: @TulaMaagar try to use `onChange` insted of `onInput` maybe it helps, your `e.target.value` is undefined, that's why it logs `undefined`

Comment: error in onChange: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Lets try `onChange={(value, viewUpdate) => {
        console.log('value:', value);
      }}` this is from official [docs](https://uiwjs.github.io/react-codemirror/)